# How to label files with incrementing numbers in bash/Cygwin?

Tags: bash, cygwin, counter, file-rename

At work, I frequently generate series of .png images produced by an oscilloscope while testing circuits.  I like to label the images with descriptive titles afterward to keep track of which image was for which measurement.  Normally I use Cygwin to rename them in batches and then go back manually to add numbers to their names, but this is very tedious if there are a lot of samples from different tests.  I am trying to write a bash script that will work to label them quickly and easily.

For example, if I have the files

scope1.png,
scope2.png,
scope3.png,
scope4.png

how would I write a bash script that could label them as

circuit_1_sample_1.png,
circuit_1_sample_2.png,
circuit_2_sample_1.png,
circuit_2_sample_2.png

I could probably do this quite easily in python, but is there an easy way to make bash or Cygwin do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You could add python to your Cygwin installation by using the Cygwin setup application.

Comment: How do you know which scope number corresponds to which circuit/sample number?

Comment: I normally keep the samples consistent and methodical.  Example, first three samples would be for circuit 1, second three for circuit 2, etc.

Comment: if there is any chance you'll need to number more that 9 units, consider using a `099` sort of format (leading zeros). It's really frustrating to have the 10's values mixed in with the `1`s. You'd use something like `$(printf "%03d" $num)` to insert/append that into your `mv` command line. (work with sample/copies first, right? ;-) ) . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If all scopes are for the same circuit:

```
for f in scope*.png; do mv "$f" "circuit_1_sample_${f/scope/}"; done
```

if only scopes 9-12 are for the same circuit:

```
for f in scope{9..12}.png; do ...
```

If it's literally exactly like your question where there are two scopes per circuit:

```
for f in scope*.png; do 
    num=${f//[^0-9]/}
    mv "$f" "circuit_$(( num / 2 ))_sample_$(( num % 2)).png"
done
```

Globing or `*` works like you'd expect, it finds all files in the current directory that could match that pattern, with `*` as a multi-character wildcard. `$(( ))` is just bash arithmetic, and works like you'd expect (integer only). the `${f/...}` stuff is [bash parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). It's pretty cool; you should read about it.